# SAML2 with Django stuck on infinite loop

Tags: django, saml-2.0

I am trying to use the [djangosaml2 1.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/djangosaml2/) module in order to implement SSO login.

After the successful login, it gets stuck in an infinite loop trying to constantly login again.

I have tried to remove the `@login_requried` decorator, it works on then.

But, I need the `@login_required` decorator in order to prevent not logged in users to access specific views.

My believe is that **django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend** is not properly configured with **djangosaml2.backends.Saml2Backend**

This is my code:
settings.py

```
SAML_CONFIG = {
  # full path to the xmlsec1 binary programm
  'xmlsec_binary': '/usr/bin/xmlsec1',

  # your entity id, usually your subdomain plus the url to the metadata view
  'entityid': 'http://localhost:8000/saml2/metadata/',

  # directory with attribute mapping
  'attribute_map_dir': path.join(BASEDIR, 'attribute-maps'),

  # this block states what services we provide
  'service': {
      # we are just a lonely SP
      'sp' : {
          'name': 'Federated Django sample SP',
          'name_id_format': saml2.saml.NAMEID_FORMAT_PERSISTENT,

          # For Okta add signed logout requets. Enable this:
          # "logout_requests_signed": True,

          'endpoints': {
              # url and binding to the assetion consumer service view
              # do not change the binding or service name
              'assertion_consumer_service': [
                  ('http://localhost:8000/tacdb/items/',
                   saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                  ],
              # url and binding to the single logout service view
              # do not change the binding or service name
              'single_logout_service': [
                  # Disable next two lines for HTTP_REDIRECT for IDP's that only support HTTP_POST. Ex. Okta:
                  ('http://localhost:8000/saml2/ls/',
                   saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),
                  ('http://localhost:8000/saml2/ls/post',
                   saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                  ],
              },
           # Mandates that the identity provider MUST authenticate the
           # presenter directly rather than rely on a previous security context.
          'force_authn': False,

           # Enable AllowCreate in NameIDPolicy.
          'name_id_format_allow_create': False,

           # attributes that this project need to identify a user
          'required_attributes': ['username'],

           # attributes that may be useful to have but not required
          'optional_attributes': ['eduPersonAffiliation'],

          # in this section the list of IdPs we talk to are defined
          # This is not mandatory! All the IdP available in the metadata will be considered.
          'idp': {
              # we do not need a WAYF service since there is
              # only an IdP defined here. This IdP should be
              # present in our metadata

              # the keys of this dictionary are entity ids
              'https://localhost/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php': {
                  'single_sign_on_service': {
                      saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT: 'https://localhost/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
                      },
                  'single_logout_service': {
                      saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT: 'https://localhost/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php',
                      },
                  },
              },
          },
      },
LOGIN_URL = '/tacdb/saml2/login/'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
MIDDLEWARE.append('djangosaml2.middleware.SamlSessionMiddleware')

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'djangosaml2.backends.Saml2Backend',
)
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def item_list(request):
....

return render(
        request, "items/item_list.html", {"filter": user_filter, "form": form}
    )
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r"^tacdb/",
        include(
            [
                path('', include('tacdashboard.urls')),
                path('saml2/', include('djangosaml2.urls')),
            ]
        )
    )
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was that I did not use the correct  'assertion_consumer_service':

```
   'assertion_consumer_service': [
                  ('http://localhost:8000/tacdb/saml2/acs',
                   saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                  ],
```